# Django: Change default parameter appended in the URL in forms

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a form like this:

```
<form method="get">
        <button name="load" type="submit" value="{{game.game_id}}|{{game.champion}}">Show user's stats</button>
</form>
```

When the user submits the form, the parameter will automatically be appended into the URL like this

```
www.example.com/?load=5293733926|99
```

However, I want to add manually another parameter to the URL making the URL look like this:

```
www.example.com/?load=5293733926|99&page=2
```

If I manually type this to the URL, it goes to where I want. How should I do this? I tried adding:

`action="./?load={{game.game_id}}|{{game.champion}}&page={{game.page}}"`
and multiple other variants.

But it doesn't work, it redirects to [www.example.com/?load=5293733926|99](http://www.example.com/?load=5293733926%7C99).

Context: I have a huge list of dictionaries and if I show them all at the same time and process them, it takes a lot of time. I divided the list with Django's paginator. The forms act as a load more. By default, I show some data from the dictionary and when the user clicks the form button, some extra information is showed. However, if someone clicks the form button in page 2 `www.example.com/?page=2`, Django would redirect the user to the first page after processing the data. In order to redirect the user to the submitted button's page, I would need to redirect the user to `www.example.com/?load=5293733926|99&page=2`

It's my first time asking a question here, if some more data needs to be provided, please let me know. Thanks!

P.D: This is a piece of the list of dictionaries:

```
{"matches":[{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5304134881,"champion":99,"queue":420,"season":13,"timestamp":1622752495039,"role":"SOLO","lane":"MID"},{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5303158955,"champion":99,"queue":420,"season":13,"timestamp":1622727838679,"role":"SOLO","lane":"MID"},{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5302981978,"champion":99,"queue":420,"season":13,"timestamp":1622718693646,"role":"SOLO","lane":"MID"},{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5302393136,"champion":64,"queue":400,"season":13,"timestamp":1622666939087,"role":"NONE","lane":"JUNGLE"},{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5301715149,"champion":103,"queue":420,"season":13,"timestamp":1622640835828,"role":"DUO","lane":"MID"},{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5301720723,"champion":99,"queue":420,"season":13,"timestamp":1622638646725,"role":"SOLO","lane":"MID"},{"platformId":"EUW1","gameId":5301040032,"champion":497,"queue":420,"season":13,"timestamp":1622625968514,"role":"DUO_SUPPORT","lane":"BOTTOM"},
```

With the form, I would get the champion number and the gameId in order to process the data of the game. A piece of the game's data looks like this:

```
{"gameId":5304134881,"platformId":"EUW1","gameCreation":1622752495039,"gameDuration":1983,"queueId":420,"mapId":11,"seasonId":13,"gameVersion":"11.11.377.6311","gameMode":"CLASSIC","gameType":"MATCHED_GAME","teams":[{"teamId":100,"win":"Win","firstBlood":false,"firstTower":false,"firstInhibitor":true,"firstBaron":true,"firstDragon":false,"firstRiftHerald":true,"towerKills":11,"inhibitorKills":3,"baronKills":1,"dragonKills":4,"vilemawKills":0,"riftHeraldKills":1,"dominionVictoryScore":0,"bans":[{"championId":63,"pickTurn":1},{"championId":111,"pickTurn":2},{"championId":25,"pickTurn":3},{"championId":55,"pickTurn":4},{"championId":235,"pickTurn":5}]},{"teamId":200,"win":"Fail","firstBlood":true,"firstTower":true,"firstInhibitor":false,"firstBaron":false,"firstDragon":true,"firstRiftHerald":false,"towerKills":2,"inhibitorKills":0,"baronKills":0,"dragonKills":1,"vilemawKills":0,"riftHeraldKills":0,"dominionVictoryScore":0,"bans":[{"championId":235,"pickTurn":6},{"championId":62,"pickTurn":7},{"championId":234,"pickTurn":8},{"championId":25,"pickTurn":9},{"championId":777,"pickTurn":10}]}],"participants":[{"participantId":1,"teamId":100,"championId":98,"spell1Id":4,"spell2Id":12,"stats":{"participantId":1,"win":true,"item0":1054,"item1":3075,"item2":3047,"item3":3068,"item4":3748,"item5":3001,"item6":3340,"kills":10,"deaths":5,"assists":20,"largestKillingSpree":5,"largestMultiKill":2,"killingSprees":2,"longestTimeSpentLiving":936,"doubleKills":1,"tripleKills":0,"quadraKills":0,"pentaKills":0,"unrealKills":0,"totalDamageDealt":163173,"magicDamageDealt":58700,"physicalDamageDealt":81055,"trueDamageDealt":23417,"largestCriticalStrike":0,"totalDamageDealtToChampions":28604,"magicDamageDealtToChampions":15265,"physicalDamageDealtToChampions":13021,"trueDamageDealtToChampions":317,"totalHeal":7157,"totalUnitsHealed":1,"damageSelfMitigated":49148,"damageDealtToObjectives":7345,"damageDealtToTurrets":7345,"visionScore":16,"timeCCingOthers":36,"totalDamageTaken":33907,"magicalDamageTaken":9592,"physicalDamageTaken":18466,"trueDamageTaken":5848,"goldEarned":14812,"goldSpent":13775,"turretKills":3,"inhibitorKills":1,"totalMinionsKilled":163,"neutralMinionsKilled":8,"neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle":4,"neutralMinionsKilledEnemyJungle":4,"totalTimeCrowdControlDealt":264,"champLevel":18,"visionWardsBoughtInGame":1,"sightWardsBoughtInGame":0,"wardsPlaced":10,"wardsKilled":0,"firstBloodKill":false,"firstBloodAssist":false,"firstTowerKill":false,"firstTowerAssist":false,"firstInhibitorKill":false,"firstInhibitorAssist":false,"combatPlayerScore":0,"objectivePlayerScore":0,"totalPlayerScore":0,"totalScoreRank":0,"playerScore0":0,"playerScore1":0,"playerScore2":0,"playerScore3":0,"playerScore4":0,"playerScore5":0,"playerScore6":0,"playerScore7":0,"playerScore8":0,"playerScore9":0,"perk0":8437,"perk0Var1":2259,"perk0Var2":1714,"perk0Var3":0,"perk1":8446,"perk1Var1":3620,"perk1Var2":0,"perk1Var3":0,"perk2":8444,"perk2Var1":2027,"perk2Var2":0,"perk2Var3":0,"perk3":8451,"perk3Var1":269,"perk3Var2":0,"perk3Var3":0,"perk4":9111,"perk4Var1":2635,"perk4Var2":600,"perk4Var3":0,"perk5":9104,"perk5Var1":12,"perk5Var2":40,"perk5Var3":0,"perkPrimaryStyle":8400,"perkSubStyle":8000,"statPerk0":5005,"statPerk1":5008,"statPerk2":5002},"timeline":{"participantId":1,"creepsPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":5.199999999999999,"0-10":4.3,"20-30":5.7},"xpPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":562.5,"0-10":446.4,"20-30":638.2},"goldPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":418,"0-10":304.1,"20-30":514.8},"csDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-0.8000000000000003,"0-10":-2.2,"20-30":1.1999999999999997},"xpDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":56.50000000000003,"0-10":40.79999999999998,"20-30":232.3},"damageTakenPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":666.8,"0-10":686,"20-30":1504.1},"damageTakenDiffPerMinDeltas":{"10-20":-519.2,"0-10":18.00000000000003,"20-30":-1596.5},"role":"SOLO","lane":"TOP"}},
```

Comment: The question is why form, why not a regular hyperlinks (views), what are you submitting to the server as a form. You can do the this with hyperlinks.

Comment: Thanks for the question, I added the answer in the original post.

Comment: I think view will be a better fit here